# Windows Server and memory dump

Tags: windows, memory

I have a working Windows Server and I need a full memory dump (for forensic purposes), but I don't want to shut down this machine.
Is any good external tool which can do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a working Windows Server on VM. I want to create a full memory dump without turning off the operating system. I need this dump because I must check e.x. what programs were turned on. When I turn off this VM I'll lose those informations.

In the past, I used one tool for this task, but that was once and I forgot the tool name.

Comment: You might be able to use LiveKD and WinDbg. To write a complete dump.  
`.\livekd64.exe -o all.dmp` having copied livekd64.exe to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\`. This will be a "Kernel Complete Dump File: Full address space is available".  So should include user and kernel mode. No restart required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cause a crash that will generate the memory dump, use the utility
[NotMyFault](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/notmyfault)
by Mark Russinovich.

You may even choose the crash type :

[image]

Ensure that Windows is set to create a full dump and not a minidump.

---

If you just wish to dump the computer memory, these tools might
help:

- [Belkasoft Live RAM Capturer](https://belkasoft.com/ram-capturer)
- [MAGNET RAM Capture](https://www.magnetforensics.com/resources/magnet-ram-capture/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But this will restart my VM, and I'd rather avoid this... I found FTK Imager, but I prefer something more lightweight

Comment: For pure memory dump I added a couple of utilities.